# Ubuntu 20.04 Utility to fix W: Duplicate sources.list entry

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources, duplicate

I get "W: Duplicate sources.list entry" messages when using the `~$ sudo apt install` or `~$ sudo apt update` commands. These are caused by duplicate sources listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files.

Does anybody know of a CLI or GUI utility that makes it easier to clean up these duplicates? It is very tedious to open and close each file in `sources.list.d/` looking for and fixing duplicate entries. Searches in AskUbuntu and on the web have so far produced nothing.

Comment: The sources file is just that a file. There is nothing to open and close. Post the contents of the sources file in the body of the question so we can see where the errors are coming from.

Comment: Since the error mesage tells you which repo is duplicated, you can find the files involved with a `grep -r`. Surely you don't have a whole lot of these duplicate entries!

Comment: You can use your ordinary Software & Updates control panel to clean up duplicates. Also note that the 'duplicate' warnings tells you exactly where both duplicates are located -- there is no need for tedious wandering.

Answer (score 0):

The utility `add-apt-repository` is aimed at adding or removing repositories into `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Besides, Ubuntu has a graphical tool, "Software and updates", that allows adding/removing a repository.

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the contents in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` may also be edited manually.

Comment: The content of sources.list and the files in the sources.list.d folder are pure text files. `sudo nano file` will launch the `nano`(similar to pico) editor on a file in `/etc/`.